# What is the using of jumper on motherboard

Tags: motherboard, desktop-computer

My Foxconn G41 MXE motherboard has a jumper, under the jumper wrighted MEM OC 1333.

What is the purpose of this jumper?

Comment: Did you check the motherboards manual?

Comment: @Hennes yes, but in my motherboard there is two jumbers, one is CLR CMOS the manualls only write about this jumber, i know using of this

Comment: How would any of us know more than what the manual has listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the manual, the motherboard supports dual channel DDR3 at 800 and 1066 MHz. The front side bus however is 1333 MHz.

Probably the jumper is a unsupported overclocking mechanism to run the memory at 1333 MHz (if your memory supports that speed). Since it is not supported, it is not mentioned in the manual. Be careful, because setting it might void your warranty.